# How to transpose a jQuery Datatable structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, transpose

I have a datatable that is editable, and each row has a "child" datatable.

The problem is that the child datatable has so many fields, and I would like to transpose it to have a vertical orientation.

Meaning that the field headers are rows and the table data show as columns...

Please note that each child table has only one row of data, so the resulting transposed data table should consist of 2 columns, one for headers and the other for the data...

Also note that I have disabled pagination, filters and sorting for the child datatable, but I have initialized it to be support inline editing...

It is of the following structure:

```
 $('#myDataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.group + tr td.details-control', function () {
            //console.log($(this).closest('tr'));
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
            //console.log(table.row(tr).data());
            if (row.child.isShown())
            {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
              var batata=  $('#myDataTablex').DataTable({
                    "info":false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bPaginate":false

              });

              $('#myDataTablex').dataTable().makeEditable({

                  "aoColumns": [
                 ......columnByColumnDefinitions here...]
              });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5992/rotate-table  Not sure it fits your needs

Comment: I tried the JS provided there but I wasn't sure how it was used without the handlers they used....

Comment: Why not modify `format` function instead so it looks like you want as shown in [Row details example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)?

Comment: Because then it wouldn't follow the format of a datatable... I mentioned the details for a reason m8

Comment: @A.Wolff Also because it is for an older version of datatables and it no longer is supported, it doesn't work....